# Hostgator file access without domain name

Tags: apache, hosting, cpanel

I have hosted my REST API at Hostgator. I do not have a domain name.

Previously I accessed my API using this format:  `{IP}/~{username}/{folder name}`. But this no longer works, the company says it's a temporary way and they restricted it for security issues. But they do not say any alternative.

How can I access my API now? I have used a domain when I created the hosting account but did not renew.

Comment: You cannot access without a domain name is what all have indicated.

Answer (score 3):

```
http://server####.temp.domains/~username/addon
```

You can see the documentation here:
https://www.hostgator.com/help/article/temporary-url

Comment: this worked for my "baby" plan on hostgator. you can find the server # and username on your "Server Info & Settings" page when you click on "dashboard" and then click on a the "manage" button on a specific package and then click "settings".

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you don't have access to the domain name that you used while purchasing the Hostgator account.

Purchase a new domain name and update its nameservers to that provided by Hostgator. Login to your Hostgator Billing Portal. 
The URL is https://portal.hostgator.com

1. Click on the packages tab.
2. Click on the settings icon in front of your package.
3. Click on "Change Domain". Enter new domain name and click "Update Domain".

This is now your new primary domain. 
And you can access your folder/API using the link : http://newDomain.com/folderName

Comment: I want to access without using a domain name

Answer (score 0):

Usually you can access like this link
http://IP_ADDRESS/~DOMAIN_FOLDER/

But I don't think so Reseller & Shared hosting can access with this trick.